# Finding upper/lowercase letters in a string

Tags: java, string

Hey guys i am programming java and am using eclipse and i am wondering if you can help me with something
so i have a program that gets an input from the user that is a string it looks like this

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class jean_Program1 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //input scanner
        Scanner input = new Scanner (System.in);
        System.out.println("Please enter a string");
        String s = input.nextLine();


    }
}
```

so i want this code to do two thing and that is after the user enters the string (for example if he/she enters `UnkjYRoIrWpe`) how can can i further build this code  to print how many uppercase and lowercase letters are in his/her string.

so i want the output to look like this

```
                 Please enter a String
                 UnkjYRoIrWpe
                 You have 5 uppercase letters
                 You have 7 lowercase letters
```

do i need a loop?

Comment: Have a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13150730/finding-all-uppercase-letters-of-a-string-in-java

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please take some time to visit the [help] and learn what makes a good question on SO.

Answer (score 0):

All the solutions I can think of require a loop, so here is the simplest I can think of:

```
int upperCount = 0, lowerCount = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i+) {
    if (Character.isUpperCase(s.charAt(i))) {
        upperCount++;
    } else {
        lowerCount++;
    }
}
```

Then, you merely have to print the values.