# Program to Sort the String

Tags: string, sorting

I want to sort the String s = "eBaDcAfg153E" Such that the sorted string contains All lowercase first and then uppercase letters and then numbers.

The output should be like   s = "acefgABDE135"

Can anyone help me with that?

Comment: There is no place for this!, do you want write for you!?

Comment: What have you tried already? What specifically do you need help with?

Comment: In which programming language ? Please add it to question tags

Comment: The SO community expects questioners to show at least a minimal effort to solve problems. Hence, I'd like to advise you to show what you have done so far (i.e. show your code) and where it failed. Having said this, this task could be easily accomplished if performance does not matter, or it could be complicated if you'd like to save every CPU cycle possible. A good starting point would be reading about sorting algorithms (quicksort, bubblesort and so on).

Comment: Hi @BR_K, [Hint](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13150786/5813861) for you. this way you can solve your program.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `StringBuilder` for string modification.

```
public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
        {
            String inputString = "eBaDcAfg153E";
            String lowerCase = "";
            String upperCase = "";
            String numberCase = "";
            
            for (int i = 0; i < inputString.length(); i++) {
               char c = inputString.charAt(i);
               if(Character.isUpperCase(c)) {
                   upperCase += c;
               }else if (Character.isLowerCase(c)) {
                   lowerCase += c;
               }else if(Character.isDigit(c)) {
                   numberCase += c;
               }
              
            }
            char upperArray[] = upperCase.toCharArray(); 
            char lowerArray[] = lowerCase.toCharArray(); 
            char numArray[] = numberCase.toCharArray(); 
            
            Arrays.sort(upperArray);
            Arrays.sort(lowerArray);
            Arrays.sort(numArray);
            
            System.out.println(new String(lowerArray)+""+new String(upperArray)+""+new String(numArray));
        }
```